# How to invoke javascript OOPS based class in another javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript class called "LayoutProcessor".js ,defined as follow:

```
define('layoutProcessor', ['jquery'], function($) {
  "use strict";
  function LayoutProcessor() {
    return (this);
  }

  LayoutProcessor.prototype.process = function() {
    console.log('inside process');
  };

  LayoutProcessor.prototype.responseHandler = function() {
    console.log('inside responseHandler');
  };

  return new LayoutProcessor();
});
```

I am trying to access the method "process" in another javascript class called "test.js", which is defined as follow:

test.js

```
require(['LayoutProcessor.js','jquery'], function(layoutProcessor,$) { 
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var response = new LayoutProcessor().process();
  });
})
```

But I am getting a type error:

> `new LayoutProcessor()` is not a constructor.

Comment: new LayoutProcessor.process()

Answer (score 1):

As per the implementation by OP, it should be

```
var response = layoutProcessor.process();
```

not

```
var response = new LayoutProcessor().process();
```

Please refer the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4w5s8p9/)**

[image]

The error message is appropriate, as its not a constructor but an object.

```
new LayoutProcessor() is not a constructor.
```

LayoutProcessor.js returns an `Object`.

```
return new LayoutProcessor();
```

Comment: I tried var response = layoutProcessor.process(); , but i am getting error:TypeError: layoutProcessor is undefined

Comment: What error is it throwing now? Have you checked the **fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/y4w5s8p9/**?

Comment: Yes, I checked the fiddle. layoutProcessor.process returns undefined.

Comment: That's correct. Isn't it? ``layoutProcessor.process`` is only **logging to console** but **not returning any value**. Should you update the function to **return any value**, you would receive it in ``response``.

Comment: yes, you are correct. The fiddle works fine but when I include LayoutProcessor.js in my test.js , I get error layoutProcessor is undefined. Here is the sample code  test.js

require(['/myloc/js/LayoutProcessor.js','jquery'], function(layoutProcessor,$) { 
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var response = layoutProcessor.process();
  });
})

Comment: Is the ``LayoutProcessor.js`` loading in the browser?

Comment: Yes, i checked in firebug console, its getting loaded with a status 200

Answer (score 0):

There are few things going on with those code.

The way it is current written, LayoutProcessor module returns a *constructed object*, not a constructor to call.

To call it you would use:

```
var response = layoutProcessor.process();
```

However, this makes a singleton, which I doubt is what you mean.

In a singleton, there will only be *one* instance if layoutProcessor, since that instance is created by the LayoutProcessor module.

I believe the code that you mean would be more like this, where you create a new instance of the object for everyone that needs it:

**layoutProcessor**

```
define('layoutProcessor', ['jquery'],
  function($) {

    "use strict";
    //----------------------------------------
    /**
     * constructor
     */
    function LayoutProcessor() {
      return (this);
    }

    LayoutProcessor.prototype.process = function() {

      console.log('inside process');

    };

    LayoutProcessor.prototype.responseHandler = function() {
      console.log('inside responseHandler');

    };

    // Note: Return a FUNCTION reference to be called later.
    return LayoutProcessor;
  }
);
```

**test.js**

```
require(['LayoutProcessor.js', 'jquery'],
  function(LocalLayoutProcessor, $) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

      var response = new LocalLayoutProcessor().process();
    });

  }
)
```

Comment: With first option:var response = layoutProcessor.process();, I am getting error: TypeError: layoutDefnProcessor is undefined                                                              With second approach : var response = new LocalLayoutProcessor().process(); ,I am getting error TypeError: LocalLayoutProcessor is not a constructor
 

                              Any pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Only issue is `return` statement. it should be

```
return LayoutProcessor;
```